# Spark submit Scala jar using Boto3

Tags: python, scala, boto3, amazon-emr

When I spin up an EMR cluster manually in the AWS console, I
run the following after SSH'ing into my cluster:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --deploy-mode cluster --class spark_pkg.SparkMain 
s3://mybucket/scala-1.0.jar -s arg1 -l arg1
```

How do I do this when using Boto3 in Python? Here is my `steps` code:

```
steps = [
            {
            'Name': 'Running jar file',   
                    'ActionOnFailure': 'TERMINATE_CLUSTER',
                    'HadoopJarStep': {
                        'Jar': 's3://mybucket/{0}'.format(jar_file),
                        'Args': ['spark-submit', '--master yarn-cluster', 
                                '--deploy-mode cluster', '--class spark_pkg.SparkMain', 
                                '-s', arg1, '-l', arg2
                        ]
                    }
                }
        ]
```

It looks like these arguments are incorrect:
`'spark-submit', '--master yarn-cluster', '--deploy-mode cluster', '--class spark_pkg.SparkMain'`

And the error I am getting is below. How can I correctly define those arguments?

```
Error: Unknown argument 'spark-submit'
Error: Unknown option --master yarn-cluster
Error: Unknown option --deploy-mode cluster
Error: Unknown option --class spark_pkg.SparkMain
Usage: spark-zoning [options]

  -l, --id1 <value>  
  -s --id2 <value>
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: None (of class scala.None$)
    at spark_pkg.SparkMain$.main(SparkMain.scala:208)
    at spark_pkg.SparkMain.main(SparkMain.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Comment: Can you provide a larger snippet of your code?

Comment: It's possible that environment variables are not correctly set and `spark-submit` is not available. Can you try replacing it with `/usr/bin/spark-submit`?

Answer (score 0):

**Boto3 handles job submittion to EMR cluster**

Args - arguments which are directly passed to jar

From previous args cmd will be:

`jar_file spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --deploy-mode cluster --class spark_pkg.SparkMain -s arg1 -l arg2`

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Running jar file",   
    "ActionOnFailure": "TERMINATE_CLUSTER",
    "HadoopJarStep": {
      "Jar": "s3://mybucket/{0}".format(jar_file),
      "Args": [
        "-s", arg1, "-l", arg2
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

After args changes cmd will be:
`jar_file -s arg1 -l arg2`

Answer (score 0):

That is due to enviroment variable are not accessible for Boto3 handler.
You have to set the environment variable in the file /etc/enviroment as like

1. `sudo nano /etc/environment`

This will open the file

```
2.PATH="/usr/local/spark/bin:/usr/local/spark/sbin"
```

You need to append the spark path in the above Variable- PATH followed by colon : if availabe else you need to directly (Note you need to change /usr/local/spark/ to you spark location.
3.`SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark` (`need to change /usr/local/spark to your spark location if different`.)

4. `CTRL + s`
5. `CTRL + x`
6. `source /etc/environment`

after that it must work.